# Use HashMap or something similar to store lists of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have several classes that all extend a certain class. I want to use a `HashMap` or something similar to hold an `ArrayList` for each of those classes, as kind of shown below.

```
HashMap<? extends MasterClass, ArrayList<? extends MasterClass>>
```

I want to call `get` with the extended class. This should return the `ArrayList` of that class. Is this possible?

```
get(Class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `Class<? extends MasterClass>` as key of your map:

```
Map<Class<? extends MasterClass>, List<? extends MasterClass>> map 
    = new HashMap<Class<? extends MasterClass>, List<? extends MasterClass>>();
```